# Creating a mini store with property getters used Vue.observable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I currently import the createStore function into a store.js file. In the file, I pass an object with state properties and mutation functions as an argument. This is working well.

**createStore.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
 
function createStore({ state, mutations }) {
  return {
    state: Vue.observable(state),
    commit(key, ...args) {
      mutations[key](state, ...args)
    }
  }
}
 
export default createStore
```

**store.js**

```
import create from './createStore.js'

const store = create ({
    state: {
      counter: 0
    },
    mutations: {
      increment(state, payload){
        state.counter += payload
      }
    }
})

export default store
```

What I'm trying to do now is the createStore function to receive a getters property and execute the function I call within a component. Example:

**CompExample.vue**

```
computed: {
  counter() {
    return store.getters.counter
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your store getters (similar to Vuex's getters) from a given `getters` map:

1. Declare a new object to store our new getters (named `myGetters`).
2. Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on `getters` to get its keys and values.
3. On each key/value pair, use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#defining_a_getter_on_existing_objects_using_defineproperty) on `myGetters` to define a getter that invokes the value (if it's a function) with `state` as the argument.

```js
function createStore({ state, mutations, getters }) {
  1️⃣
  const myGetters = {}

  if (getters) {
    2️⃣
    Object.entries(getters).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      3️⃣
      Object.defineProperty(myGetters, key, {
        get: () => typeof value === 'function' ? value(state) : value
      })
    })
  }

  return {
    //...
    getters: myGetters
  }
}
```

Then initialize it in `store.js` like this:

```js
const store = createStore({
  //...
  getters: {
    counter: state => state.counter,
    half: state => state.counter / 2,
    double: state => state.counter * 2,
    square: state => Math.pow(state.counter, 2)
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-store-in-vue-f27up?file=/src/createStore.js)